# Proper "a" and gustar

Tags: objetos-directos, a-personal

I've looked around on this site, and I don't see a direct answer to this question, and it's kind of bugging me.

Using "a" in front of proper nouns, when they are a direct object, mostly makes sense to me. As in, "Juan llama a su madre". However, I get stuck a lot when trying to identify the DO. I can manage it most of the time, by asking "who" or "what" receives the action. But, there's one place where it just doesn't make sense to me. When using gustar. For instance, "a él le gusta su madre". It seems to me that the subject is "he", and the DO is "his mother". However, it seems that "he" is the direct object, in this case? Or is this a verb where there is an exception to the "personal a" rule? Or is it because the verb doesn't actually mean "to like" as so many people espouse, but rather " pleasing "?

My research has been Duolingo, (yes, I'm VERY much a Spanish rookie, but I absolutely love Spanish!) and sites like "spanishdict.com" and "learnspanish.com". There have also been a few short papers from college classes that I've read on the subject, but I still don't have a solid answer, and I am very much a logical learner. So, I really need know the mechanics of the language!

Help!?

Comment: Nota al margen: desconozco qué tipo de aprendizaje estás haciendo, pero a menos que seas un lingüista experto creo que lo más fácil es comenzar aprendiendo vocabulario y expresiones típicas de conversación. Se me hace que te vas a agobiar muy rápido. Una vez hayas ganado una fluidez razonable, ahí sí es buena idea pulirte con estos detalles técnicos. Como sea, si en tu cátedra empiezan estudiando los objetos sintácticos, no soy quién para contradecir

Answer (score 6):

In Spanish, verbs of liking and disliking only take an indirect object introduced by "a". This should not be confused with personal direct objects introduced by "a".

With verbs taking direct objects introduced by "a", the passive voice is possible. With verbs of liking and disliking taking indirect objects introduced by "a", the passive voice is not possible.

Also, while the direct object can be replaced with "la", "lo", "las", "los", with verbs of liking and disliking the indirect object needs to be reinforced by "le" or "les".

- Juan llama **a su madre** (La madre es llamada por Juan: this passive is awkward but grammatically correct) => Juan **la** llama.
- Juan ama **a su padre**. (El padre es amado por Juan.) => Juan **lo** ama.

With verbs of liking and disliking, the "a"-complement introduces the person (or animal) that experiences pleasure or displeasure, and the person or object causing that feeling is the subject. Within this group of verbs, we find *gustar, disgustar, encantar, apetecer, agradar, desagradar, apasionar, satisfacer, entusiasmar, interesar, repugnar, complacer*:

- **A Juan le** gusta su amiga.

Here, "a Juan" and "le" are indirect objects (both refer to the same person, and "le" is required) and "su amiga" is the subject.

You can imagine the sentence above as equivalent to:

- Juan's friend appeals to him. (The friend is the one causing the appeal, and Juan is the one experiencing it.)

In this structure, the object introduced by "a" is always animate because only people and animals can experience emotions like liking, disliking, interest, repulsion, pleasure, enthusiasm, etc.

Another example where the indirect object is an animal:

- **A mi perro le** encantan los huesos. (The subject is "los huesos", which agrees with the plural verb "encantan".)

Comment: great answer, very thorough explanation

Answer (score 2):

Gustar is typically translated as 'to like' in English. This is confusing. If it is translated, instead, as 'to please', it makes better sense.

"a él le gusta su madre" could then be understood as "his mother pleases him", and "a él" is clearly the direct object.

Using "to please" as the translation also makes the verb form (e.g. "a mi me gustan las manzanas" => "apples please me") consistent in English and Spanish, where translating gustar as 'to like' introduces an inconsistency in the translation.

Comment: This is not a bad way to remember how gustar works when first learning, but since it doesn’t sound at all natural in English you typically end up translating it as ‘to like’. Better to understand the grammar behind it and be able to apply that to all the other verbs that function like gustar