# Me gustan las manzanas. No direct object?

Tags: gramática

While reading through various grammar lessons, I always thought there had to be a direct object, but this case, there is only an indirect object (me)?

"Me gustan las manzans"

Comment: the verb like in Spanish functions differently than other verbs.

Comment: This can help: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/42383/14676

Answer (score 1):

Así es. En este caso el análisis correcto sería:

- Sujeto: ‘las manzanas’
- Verbo: ‘gustan’
- Objeto Indirecto: ‘(a mí) me’

En contraste con la traducción al inglés:

- Sujeto: ‘I’
- Verbo: ‘like’
- Objeto Directo: ‘apples’

Sintácticamente hablando, yo no diría que el sujeto tiene que ser la persona/agente que realice la acción. La mejor forma de reconocer el sujeto consiste en **identificar qué es lo que tiene que concordar con el verbo**:

> Me gusta la manzana
> Me gusta**n** la**s** manzana**s**

Sabemos que el verbo es ‘gusta(n)’. Al cambiar el verbo al plural (o al singular), vemos que es ‘manzana(s)’ la palabra que tiene que concordar, por lo tanto es el sujeto. Luego, ‘me’ es el objeto indirecto por descarte.

Si optáramos por una definición inadecuada de sujeto sintáctico (persona o agente que realiza la acción) todavía no estamos equivocados en el análisis si reconocemos que son las manzanas las que *causan* la emoción de gustar. Pero **si** además de esto, **lo pensamos como en el inglés** (‘I like apples’, como si yo fuera quien realiza la acción de ‘gustar’), **entonces sí que meteríamos la pata** debido a que llegaríamos a la conclusión de que el sujeto sería ‘a mí’ (~ I), el verbo sería ‘me gustan’ (~ like) y el objeto directo sería ‘las manzanas’ (~ apples), lo cual es sintácticamente incorrecto. Probablemente sea esto lo que originó tu confusión—y la mía.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the apples are affected by the action of liking--actually, they cause that emotion, and that's why they are the subject in Spanish.

Comment: Puede ser, es que yo tiendo a pensarlo al revés como ocurre en inglés: ‘I like the apples’, ‘yo gusto las manzanas’, como si fuera yo el que lo está haciendo. Ahora lo aclaro, gracias

Comment: Me gustan las manzanas=literally, apples are pleasing to me, i.e. I like apples.

Comment: @Lambie ‘apples are pleasing to me’ mapea al castellano como ‘las manzanas son placenteras para mí’, construcción para nada natural. Por estas cosas no recomiendo analizar un idioma en base a meras traducciones ‘literales’, situación que aplica también para ‘I am him’ ;)

Comment: No es así.  El español es Me encantan las manzanas que literalmente en inglés es: Apples are pleasing to me. **La lengua fuente es el español, y la traducción literal hacia el inglés es solo para *demostrar la estructura del español***. Soy traductora del español hacia el inglés hace 35 años.

Comment: @Lambie No creo que dicha traducción sea útil para explicar lo que necesita entender el OP. Sin embargo, si considerás que es un mejor recurso explicativo, te invito a escribir tu respuesta. A lo mejor vende más que la mía

Comment: Of course it helps. Just like: She is pleasing to me; they are pleasing to me. For an English speaker, it is imperative to understand the structure of the Spanish with English literal examples. That's one way an English speaker learns how these verbs work **in Spanish**.

Comment: @Lambie Es que yo quiero que piensen como lo hace un nativo, al cual ni siquiera se le pasan por la cabeza estas cosas. Antes de responder le mostré la pregunta a mis viejos y dijeron literalmente lo que puse en el último párrafo (‘me’ = sujeto y ‘las manzanas’ = obj directo). Todavía piensan que es así. Yo pensaba lo mismo hasta que investigué. Aún sigo pensando en mi cabeza que es así, para mí responder a este tipo de preguntas es una mera formalidad. Pienso que en realidad la sintaxis no refleja del todo bien cómo funcionan nuestras cabezas.

Comment: @Lambie Así que no, no me lo creo. Y en todo caso yo eligiría algo como ‘Apples delight me’, me parece algo mucho más acertado en lugar de usar una construcción con gerundio (‘are pleasing’) que agrega distorsiones innecesarias. En última instancia quizá  deberíamos recurrir a la fórmula clásica ‘*traduttore = traditore*’. Tal vez, en este caso debería decir ‘*traduttrice = traditrice*’ xd

Comment: @tac gustar is translated for interpretation purposes into English as being literally **X pleases or is pleasing to me**. And I think a native speaker knows more about translating **into English** than a Spanish speaker. I rest my case.